# MySql performance slows after adding 'or' in where clause

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a a query that runs for **7 secs** when the filter criteria is

```
select * from table where date1 is  null
```

but when I add

```
select * from table where (date1 is  null or (date1 < date2) )
```

then the query takes **32 secs**. How do I improve the performance on this query? I have indexes on both the date columns.

Comment: Have you checked the results of `EXPLAIN` for both queries?

Comment: Try using a `UNION`, take off the `OR` and put that condition in the other select

Comment: are the fields indexed?

Comment: I tried  UNION/UNION ALL but it don't see any improvement the date1 is null comes back in 7 sec and the second one takes 24 secs. I tried the explain and  1 PRIMARY <derived6> ALL     79242 Using temporary; Using filesort
 6 DERIVED d ALL PRIMARY,IX2,IX3    1411281 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: I tried  UNION/UNION ALL but it don't see any improvement the date1 is null comes back in 7 sec and the second one takes 24 secs.  I tried the explain and I think two operations which are not using indexes not sure how to post these rows without messing the formatting .I think the query one of the views being used is not using the indexes from the base table . id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows extra
1 PRIMARY <derived6> ALL     79242 Using temporary; Using filesort
6 DERIVED d ALL PRIMARY,IX2,IX3    1411281 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: What kinds of column are date1 and date2? Date, datetime, char/varchar, string, int, or something else?

Comment: @user1721546 Please add the results of `EXPLAIN` to the question. In the comments, it's just a mess very hard to read. )

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing SQL to compare the 2 dates first, before if can evaluate the rest of the condition.

You should see improvement by writing it so:

```
select * from table where date1 is null or date1 < date2
```

This will make for a faster resolution accomplishment since the condition will be true the moment the first condition is met.

Comment: This didn'nt make a diffference